# Exploding not working in pandas as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like below:

```
Group   Attributes  S2SFlag
Age 1 to 5  Yes
Age 6 to 10 No
Channel DD  No
Channel Agency  Yes
Status  Lapse   Yes
Status  Active  Yes
```

Now I want to explode the values of the `'Age'` group by the range defined in the `attributes` column while retaining other column values.

The  **`expected output`** is as below:

[image]

Attempt so far:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('')
df1 = df1[df1['Group'] == 'Age']
attrList = df1['Attributes'].tolist()
for i in attrList:
    start = i.split(" to ")[0]
    end = i.split(" to ")[1]
    for j in range(int(start), int(end) + 1):
        df1['Attributes'] = str(j)
```

It is giving me output as below:

```
 Group Attributes S2SFlag
0   Age         10     Yes
1   Age         10      No
```

Comment: please provide your data as **text**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom function to replace the string with `range`, then `explode`:

```
import re

def to_range(s):
    m = re.match('(\d+) to (\d+)$', s)
    return range(int(m.group(1)), int(m.group(2))+1) if m else s

(df.assign(Attributes=[to_range(s) for s in df['Attributes']])
   .explode('Attributes')
)
```

output:

```
     Group Attributes S2SFlag
0      Age          1     Yes
0      Age          2     Yes
0      Age          3     Yes
0      Age          4     Yes
0      Age          5     Yes
1      Age          6      No
1      Age          7      No
1      Age          8      No
1      Age          9      No
1      Age         10      No
2  Channel         DD      No
3  Channel     Agency     Yes
4   Status      Lapse     Yes
5   Status     Active     Yes
```

Comment: Yeah, this worked. Just a question, in the future if I get values like `<5` along with range, then what needs to be modified here? Will I need any rules table for this kind of scenario?

Comment: @whatsinthename you'd need to either add a rule in the function for this case (e.g. if/elif/else) or come up with a clever regex that matches all your cases (possible and probably faster but maybe more ambiguous)